# INSERT JSON into two tables and return serial ID

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, plpgsql

I am trying to `INSERT` a new record into a Postgres 9.6 database, and take the ID of that newly inserted record and pass it to a different table for a foreign key reference. The data is in a JSON format, and I want to store the JSON blob in the row field and not parse it out. However, I am getting an error regarding a `NULL` value violating the `NOT-NULL` constraint of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

I am under the assumption that my code should create a new record in the `my_data` table (with the `data_id` auto generated and the `data_fields` filled in with my JSON object) but it appears that my assumption is incorrect.

What am I missing or not fully grasping? Below is the code to replicate my setup.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data(
  data_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  data_fields JSONB
);

CREATE TABLE request_data(
    request_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    request_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    data_id INTEGER REFERENCES my_data(data_id),
    record_count INTEGER,
    completedStatus boolean
);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updateData (
dataFields JSONB,
requestTimestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
recordCount INTEGER,
completedStatus boolean,
OUT new_record_id INTEGER
)
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO my_data SELECT * FROM jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::my_data, $1::jsonb) RETURNING data_id INTO new_record_id;
INSERT INTO request_data (request_timestamp, data_id, record_count, completed_status) VALUES($2, new_record_id, $3, $4);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT updateData (
'[{"identity": "personA", "timestamp": "2017-09-15T20: 03: 12+00: 00"},
{"identity": "personB", "timestamp": "2017-09-15T20: 03: 12+00: 00"},
{"identity": "personC", "timestamp": "2017-09-15T20: 03: 12+00: 00"}]'
 '2017-09-29', 
 3, 
 true)
```

Error:

```
ERROR: null value in column "data_id" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
Detail: Failing row contains (null, null).
```

Expected outcome for `my_data` table:

```
data_id     | data_fields
------------+------------------------------
    1       | [{"identity": "personA", "timestamp": "2017-09-15T20: 03: 12+00: 00"},{"identity": "personB", "timestamp": "2017-09-15T20: 03: 12+00: 00"},{"identity": "personC", "timestamp": "2017-09-15T20: 03: 12+00: 00"}]
```

Expected outcome for `request_data` table:

```
request_id  |    request_timestamp     | data_id | record_count | completed_status
------------+--------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------------
    1       |   2017-09-29             |  1      |  3           |   true
```

Comment: Why are you using this jsonb_populate_recordset ? Try this only insert into my_data values ($1::jsonb)  as you are using serial for column data_id.

Comment: You bring up a good point. That is the better solution.

Comment: Glad to hear I am able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fahad pointed out the primary logic error.

But you do not need the cast in <strike>`($1::jsonb)`</strike> since the input parameter is typed `jsonb` already.

And I would recommend a *single* query with a data-modifying CTE combining both inserts in a simple SQL function - instead of two `INSERT` queries with an assignment in between in a PL/pgSQL function. Shorter, less prone to errors, faster:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_data(data_fields jsonb
                                     , request_timestamp timestamptz
                                     , recordcount integer
                                     , completed_status boolean)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
   WITH ins1 AS (
      INSERT INTO my_data(data_fields)
      VALUES ($1)  -- no need to cast
      RETURNING data_id
      )
   INSERT INTO request_data(request_timestamp, data_id, record_count, completed_status)
   SELECT $2, i.data_id, $3, $4
   FROM   ins1 i
   RETURNING data_id
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

I also unified to lower case spelling. You had a mix of naming conventions resulting in a mismatch between `completedStatus` and `completed_status`. My standing advice is to avoid mixed case spelling for identifiers in Postgres.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL multi INSERT...RETURNING with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775109/postgresql-multi-insert-returning-with-multiple-columns/22775268#22775268)
- [Insert inserted id to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588544/insert-inserted-id-to-another-table/27589070#27589070)
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 0):

@Fahad Anjum pointed out the better way to insert the json. I changed my `INSERT` statement to `INSERT INTO my_data (data_fields) values($1) RETURNING data_id INTO new_record_id;` and it gives me the results I need.